# Is it okay to use my own framework for a job with another company?

Tags: frameworks, startup

I know this isn't a legal forum and not looking for legal advice, but I assume someone here will have some useful advice.

Over the last year I setup (registered) my own company so I could do freelance and contracting. During that time I built a very useful framework and ORM for building out websites. The language I am using basically only has 1 other web framework which has too many limitations for me, so I built my own.

Now I am going back into the corporate world and have just been offered CTO with a startup. My question is would it be wrong to use the framework I built as the company's main back-end technology?

I would make it open source first, so I think it's okay to do. Would I still need to disclose it as a conflict of interest?

Comment: I think you should ask your question on https://law.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: thanks, didn't know that existed

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to use a work, created inside a company that paid you for that work, for another company.

But, in this case, you said that you were a freelancer when you built this framework and that company was yours. I don't think you will have problems with your own company but maybe with your clients.

So if you really want to be safe to use that framework elsewhere, I hope you have included in your contracts as a freelancer a clause that precise that the work develops for the clients can be reuse.

I have seen that kind of clauses in the corporate world a lot.

Comment: good point, luckily not a problem. My contracts with my clients say they are only getting a license to use the framework.

Comment: So, if you gave licenses, you are still the owner of the work. I don't think you will have problem with that.